# Axios POST requests fail to use proxy

Tags: reactjs, post, proxy, axios, package.json

I'm currently testing out the endpoints on my server via a React client using Axios. I have a proxy (`http://localhost:8080`) set up in my package.JSON for my client. All my GET requests are successful. My POST requests on the other-hand all fail to make use of the proxy provided in package.JSON, instead, it's using (`http://localhost:3000`).

Please see code below

**Login Component**

```
function Login{

      const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault();

            let email = e.target.email.value;
            let password = e.target.password.value;

            axios.post("/user/login", {email:email, password:password})
           .then((res) => console.log(res))
           .catch((err) => console.log(err));
           }


      return(
       <div className="form login">
        <h1>Login</h1>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
        </div>
       );
}
```

This is the solution I tried after my original attempt failed

**Previous handleSubmit()**

```
const handleSubmit = (e) =>{

      try{
            let res = await axios({
                method: "post",
                url: "/user/login",
                data: {},
                proxy:{
                    host: "localhost",
                    port: "8080"
                }
            })

            console.log(res);

        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }

}
```

This solution also seems to direct requests to `http://localhost:3000`

[image: Client proxy failure screenshot]

**Package.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas as to how I can remedy this?
Thanks for any and all suggestions.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Restart React server.

Answer (score 2):

XMLHttpRequest doesn't provide an API to set a proxy server, so the config option isn't used with the [xhr adaptor](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/xhr.js). It is only supported by the [http adaptor](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/http.js) which is used when you run Axios under Node.js.

If you want to use a traditional proxy server, you need to manually change the configuration of the browser (or the OS if the browser picks it up from there).

Comment: Surely there must be an easier way. How can the proxy work on GET requests but not POST requests, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am have the exact same issue...